# Django query show length in a template?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am trying output the length of my query in a `template`. What is the right method to do that?

I have tried `len()`,.`count()`,`count()` but **nothing worked**.

here is my **`views.py`**:

```
@login_required
def view_contacts(request):
    print("Current User")
    current_user = request.user.get_username()
    user = User.objects.filter(username=current_user).first()

    output = UserContacts.objects.filter(current_user_id=user.id).first()

    my_dict = {'output':output,'number': output.count}

    return render(request,'basic_app/view_contacts.html',my_dict)
```

and this is my **view.contacts.html**:

```
{%extends 'basic_app/base.html' %}
{% block body_block %}

<div class = "jumbotron">   

        <p> you have {{ number }} of contacts in your address book</p>
        <p> {{ output }} </p>

</div>


{% endblock %}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

**Error:**

```
UserContacts object has no attribute count
```

Comment: tried output.count() as well it doesn't work

Comment: `count()` is applied on multiple results `first()` gives you single record

Answer (score 0):

you should replace

```
output = UserContacts.objects.filter(current_user_id=user.id).first()
```

to 
    `output = UserContacts.objects.filter(current_user_id=user.id).all()`

Comment: Because of query.first() is not a list so you can not count that